# Adding models to a list in presenter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dependency-injection, mvp

In a MVP presenter I have following code. Here what am I trying is to create a list of `Model` objects (in this case `IAttendance` objects) and to show them on a `DataGridView` in the `View`.

Every time an attendance is entered on the View, `AddAttendanceObjectToGrid()` method on the presenter will be called to add the new attendance to the list.

```
class AttendancePresenter : BasePresenter
{
    private IAttendance _Model;
    private readonly IAttendanceView _View;

    BindingSource BS = new BindingSource();
    List<IAttendance> AttendanceList = new List<IAttendance>();

    public AttendancePresenter( IAttendance model, IAttendanceView view )
    {
        _Model = model;
        _View = view;
    }

    private void AddAttendanceObjectToGrid()
    {
        SetModelPropertiesFromView(_Model, _View); // Call base class method to update the Model with data

        AttendanceList.Add(_Model); // Add new model to list
        BS.DataSource = AttendanceList; // Show list on the grid
        _View.AttendanceInGrid = BS;
    }
}
```

Since each time I'm adding a reference to a model, all the objects are in the list same. How to solve this problem?

If the solution would be using a copy constructor in my model, please show me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want Grid to display newly added object. I see two ways

- Replace Lis with ObservableCollection. ObservableCollection will notify the Grid control about added elements.
- Do a trick - BS.DataSource = null; BS.DataSource = AttendanceList;

The second option will be much slower since it will trigger clearing Grid and re-populating it by all the rows.

Edit:
The list contains multiple references to the same object, I see now.You can clone the model before setting the properties into it.

```
_Model = (IAttendance)_Model.Clone();
SetModelPropertiesFromView(_Model, _View);
AttendanceList.Add(_Model);
```

IAttendance should implement ICloneable then.

Comment: Problem is this `AttendanceList.Add(_Model);` adds a reference to the list. So finally I end up with a list of same objects (finally added one). How to overcome this?